# Split substrings within a string in C#

Tags: c#, regex, string, email

I need to check a string that contains a list of e-mails. These emails are usually separated by commas, but I need to check if somewhere in that list there is a delimiter other than a comma. Here's an example:

```
email1@email.com,email2@email.com,email3@email.com#email4@email.com
```

I need to identify that different character and replace to a comma.

I cannot just use a regex to identify special characters other than the comma and replace them because emails may have some of these characters. So I need to find something between two e-mail.
I made the following regex to identify an e-mail and I believe it will cover most of the emails:

```
^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)+$
```

But I'm a little lost on how to use it to solve my problem, using C #. I need to capture something that was between two matches of this regex and replace to a comma.

Could anyone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it a random character? It shouldn't be there in the first place I guess.
If it's random, check all the valid characters, and replace the invalid ones with a comma.
if not: `emails.Replace('#', ',')` :p

Comment: Why not only match valid email addresses and filter out the rest.

Comment: if the separator might be any valid character of the name in the email you have serious problems

Comment: Sounds like the XY problem. Fix X (the input) first, then you don't need a solution for Y (sanitizing).

Comment: The only way to do this is if you always assume .com

Comment: An idea is to split the string on the comma, and then "verify" each string in the resulting array, by making sure each string only contains one @.

Comment: is the separator in a set of well-known chars?

Comment: try this `(?<=\.\w{2,3})[^\w,]`

Comment: you you want to create a pattern that splits on a certain character, but you don't know what that character is. Seem's your missing the `Regular` part of `Regular Expression`

Comment: "*I cannot just use a regex to identify special characters other than the comma and replace them because emails may have some of these characters.*" Do you mean that an email address might contain one of the delimiters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
([^@,]+@[^.]+\.\w{3}(?!,|$)).
```

Try this.Replace by `$1,`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/tF4jD3/15

P.S this will work for email id's of format `something@something.com`.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is unsolvable because the delimiter can not always be determined by a **human**.

Consider this input where the delimiter is a `.`:

```
user@server.co.uk.user@otherServer.com
```

Is this:

```
user@server.co | uk.user@otherServer.com
```

or is it:

```
user@server.co.uk | user@otherServer.com
```

---

Or this input:

```
user@server.intuser@otherServer.com
```

Is it delimiter `u`:

```
user@server.int | ser@otherServer.com
```

Or delimiter `t`:

```
user@server.in | user@otherServer.com
```

---

If you're not willing to accept a certain percentage of failures, you're better off looking for ways not to receive this input to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of an elegant way to achieve this. If you don't mind an inelegant solution, you can replace [any top level domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) plus one character with the same TLD plus comma.

You'll end up replacing ".com#" with ".com,", ".eu*" with ".eu," and so on. Replacement could take place using Regex so your iterations will be the same number of the TLDs you want to replace.

Comment: And what about multi-level domains?

Comment: You'll also end up replacing `.com` with `.co,` due to `.co` also being a domain, and you'll also be replacing `user.com@server.net.com` with `user.com,server.net,com`

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is to split the incoming string using the @ symbol and check that each part of the resulting array has a comma in int--except the first and last.

If you find one that is missing the comma do a search for the .com or .net or .org in that element and stick a comma after that character.

Lastly just run splice the list back together with the @ symbol

Comment: And what about .com.eu?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.

The string must have only commas as the delimiter.

The example I mentioned was just to illustrate, because this list was generated using a jquery plugin that had a flaw that was noticed only after allowing it to be saved in the list something like "email1@email.comemail2@email.com" or any other combination non standard "email1@email.com,email2@email.com".

My main concern is cases like "email1@email.com/email2@email.com"

I'm trying to automate a search for this kind of inconsistency, as prevention.

I thought about using regex but I really do not know if it is the best approach.
I am now thinking, as it is not a critical part of the system, it would be a simpler way just to use a list of invalid characters to make the replace.

But I will try the vks's solution.

Thank you all.

Comment: In the future, please edit your question to introduce updates instead of posting an answer.